# How Spring boot internally knows about a controller's endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

if there are ten rest controllers in the spring boot application and each controller has 10 methods and I want to call 10th controller 9th method,

How spring boot does it efficiently internally ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is managed by Spring MVC request mapping.
Spring boot provides starter that autoconfigures Spring MVC.

In your case I suppose each method will be annotated with @RequestMapping (or one of its  HTTP method specific shortcut variants like @GetMapping, @PostMapping, ...)
You can find how @RequestMapping works  [in the spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

To sumarize it, you have to annotate each method with @RequestMapping. Spring has a generic entry point (the dispatcher servlet) that intercept all incoming requests and forward them to the right controller.

```
@RestController
public class Controller1 {
    @GetMapping("/endpoint1")
    public String method1() {
        return "Controller1.endpoint1";
    }
    @GetMapping("/endpoint2")
    public String method2() {
        return "Controller1.endpoint2";
    }
}
```

Notice that Spring Mvc doesn't allow ambigous request mapping. You cannot have more than one method with the some request mapping url (Your application will not start)